# Opening docx files in Google Drive viewer when other apps capture intent

Tags: android-10, google-drive, intents, filter, documents

I'd like to open `docx` files directly into Google Drive viewer.

When another application like Epson iPrint or Termux is installed, I don't have other choice than those apps. When they're not installed, it opens in Google Drive viewer like a charm.

I think it is related with intent-filters.

When examining manifest files :

- Termux has a VIEW intent-fiter on `application/*`.
- Epson iPrint has a VIEW intent-fiter on `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` (and others) which is the mime type of docx document.
- Google Drive has a VIEW intent-filter on `*/*` so should be able to open anything.

Is there a workaround for this problem ? (appart from uninstalling other apps of course)

Is this a bug or on purpose (thanks in advance to android devs here) ?

I already tried "Open with" type apps with no chances...